# Getting a list or count of all running threads

Tags: haskell, runtime, hook, ghc

How can I do one of the following?

- get a list of `ThreadID`s all running forked threads (preferably with labels) from application code?
- get a simple (maybe approximate; e.g. from the last major GC), count of running threads
- get either of the above from `gdb` or similar

Things that don't work for me:

- requiring a profiling build
- maintaining some data structure to try to track this information myself

Things I thought might be promising:

- write a custom eventlog hook to try to get this info [https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#hooks-to-change-rts-behaviour](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#hooks-to-change-rts-behaviour)
- create a hacky RTS binding somehow

Comment: May I ask why a tracking data structure is out of bounds? In principle, this seems like the most straightforward approach: replace calls to fork primitives with ones that update a global set or counter.

Comment: @dfeuer: That’s what I’d do with code I controlled, but I don’t believe you can easily instrument code that you *don’t* control with your replacement forks

Comment: Maybe the ThreadScope source code will be informative?

Comment: I think it's a great question (clear, well-asked, clear effort to solve it yourself first, not a dupe of a thing we've seen a million times)... I just don't think there's a satisfying answer...

Comment: @dfeuer I'd like to be able to audit whether threads are getting created but not destroyed properly, or whether they are leaking from some other place (e.g. a bug in `async` or something). I suppose I could do the former with confidence if I just store `ThreadId`s in a set and have a thread that polls them periodically and only removes them when the status shows "terminated" or whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC 9.6 [introduced](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/2816) `listThreads :: IO [ThreadId]`

From [GHC User’s Guide](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/9.6.1-notes.html?highlight=listthreads#base-library):

> GHC now provides a set of operations for introspecting on the threads of a program, GHC.Conc.listThreads, as well as operations for querying a thread’s label (GHC.Conc.threadLabel) and status (GHC.Conc.threadStatus).